# Magento 1.9 : Moved from subdomain to public_html now wysiwyg problems

Tags: url, wysiwyg, media-images, magento-1.9.3.8

I have moved my magento 1.9 from a subdomain to the folder public_html. This is now for my primary domain www.mydomain.co.uk
I have changed everything that needed changing, also now adjusted the unsecure and secure urls

I noticed that some pictures of my category descriptions had disappeared.
so I looked and found out that the WYSIWYG Editor is no open by default (which should be by the settings)
In the description I have added a picture. The path shows something like www.mydomain.co.uk/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvaW1hZ2VzL2NhdC10YWJsZS10aHVtYi5qcGcifX0,/key/2f044931a0e6fbd04b37cfdc3e7b05e2/

On the frontend this picture is not visible.

Then I changed to static URLs for the picture. Still no show on the frontend.

I then went to the frontend to see the information from this picture and it shows me that the path to this particular picture is to
www.mydomain.scot/image/catalog/cat_tea/cat_tea-400px.png

the domain ending .scot is with a different provider where the "old" website with opencart was. The domain name is now redirection to .co.uk

I have looked everywhere to change this path, it turns up to be on all pictures in the description of the categories.

I have flushed every cache there is, believe me, have double checked all paths I could find in the configuration and could not find anything that points to the .scot domain

Hope someone can help me.
thx in advance

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try following ;

Go to `System > Configuration > Content Management (Under General) > WYSIWYG Options`

‘`Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog’ – Select “No”`

Comment: I did this before, did not change a thing.

Comment: Well this settings is specifically for changing frontend urls to __directive urls found in admin, so I thought it may help.

Comment: I think you do not understand my question. No matter which setting I am using, the picture does not show up in the front end!

Comment: Any Fix for this Issue?